# Ruby Iterate from an object using ERB

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm new, was tasked to do a front end job but I thought i can figure out ERB easily.

In my app.rb
variables defined

```
def find_listings
   3.times.map { random_item }
end

def random_item
  {
    name: 'blah',
    location: 'LA'
   }
end

get '/' do
   @listings = find_listings
   erb :index
end
```

In my ERB file I am trying to iterate

index.erb

```
<% @listings.each do |value | %>    
        <strong><%= value %><br/>
        <%# This returns {:name=>"blah", :location=>"New York"} %>
        <strong><%= value['name']%></strong><br/>
        <%# This returns nothing %>  
<% end %>
```

How do i get the name value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hash has symbols as keys (not strings), so you can access name this way: `value[:name]`.

Comment: @artSir This should be working, please share you updated code wheren you make this change.